# Extract exact string within a string and append

Tags: c#

I have the following string of the format:

```
http://www.somesomesome.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=232
http://www.somesomesome.com/showproduct.aspx?ID=233
http://www.somesomesome.com/showproduct.aspx?ID=272
http://www.somesomesome.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=253
```

I want to extract "ShowProduct.aspx?ID=232" (**case-insentive** and here it can be 232 or 233 or any other number)

and append it to another string `"http://www.notthiswebsite.com/"`

and make it

```
http://www.notthiswebsite.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=232
```

How do I do it in C#?

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having with what you tried?

Comment: I know how to use the IndexOf() searchWithinThis.IndexOf(searchForThis);
but I do not know how to extract a string once the index is found. Plus the number at the end of the string, how do I make the search generic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
var uriString = "http://www.somesomesome.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=232";
var uri = new Uri(uriString);
var pathQuery = uri.PathAndQuery; //ShowProduct.aspx?ID=232
```

Now you can plus pathQuery to any string you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
  var url = "http://www.somesomesome.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=232"; 
  var newHost = "www.notthiswebsite.com";
  var finalUrl = url .Replace(new Uri(url).Host, newHost);
```

Comment: great answer M. Naseer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring` to get the last part.

```
string url = "http://www.somesomesome.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=232";
url = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf(@"/") + 1);
```

And to get the number you can do this

```
string Id = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("=") + 1);
```

If you are getting this on page load you can extract the number using `QueryString`

```
string Id="";
if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
   Id = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the URL have always the same format, you can get the [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which starts at the index `28` directly:

```
string input = "http://www.somesomesome.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=232";
string result = "http://www.notthiswebsite.com/" + input.Substring(28);
```

If the length varies, we will need to find where the `ShowProduct` part starts. To do that, we can use [`LastIndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the character `/` to find where to start. As the name implies, this method will start from the end of your string and back up until it finds the symbol.

Afterwards, we have to increment that index value by one, because we want to start our substring on the `S` and not the `/` itself:

```
string input = "http://www.somesomesome.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=232";
string result = "http://www.notthiswebsite.com/" + input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s1 = "http://www.somesomesome.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=232";
string str1 = s1.Substring(s1.LastIndexOf('/') + 1); //ShowProduct.aspx?ID=232
string str2 = "http://www.notthiswebsite.com/";
string result = str2 + str1;
```

You can use this